# Ruby, WordPress: reading the most recent posts

Tags: ruby, wordpress

Having read the WordPress docs, and done some research, it seems as if the advice on how to get the last 10 posts on a WordPress site, is to do the following:

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'
#initialize a connection
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new2('http://www.mywordpresssite.com')
result = connection.call('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', 1,'admin','123456')
#or it seems that I can also call:
result = connection.call('wp.getPages', 1,'admin','123456',10)
```

Following the connection call, I get a legitimate result:

```
 => #<XMLRPC::Client:0x007fdfec50cac0 @http_header_extra=nil, @http_last_response=nil, @cookie=nil, @host="www.mywordpresssite.com", @path="/RPC2", @proxy_host=nil, @proxy_port=nil, @use_ssl=false, @timeout=30, @port=80, @password=nil, @user=nil, @auth=nil, @http=#<Net::HTTP www.mywordpresssite.com:80 open=false>, @parser=nil, @create=nil>
```

But when I do:

```
result = connection.call('wp.getPages', 1,'admin','123456',10)
```

or

```
result = connection.call('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', 1,'admin','123456')
```

I get:

SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was having the same error message when trying to post from my Sinatra app with the xmlrpc/client.

The interesting is, when I used the same way of posting from IRB, I could successfully post to my blog.

I found out that it seems xmlrpc does not really like the protocol. I removed the

```
      http://
```

from the link and it went without a hitch. Give it a try, maybe helps.